# Format cells based on start and end date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, `Start` and `Finish` (both dates), that I would like to utilize for conditional formatting.  To the right of the Start and Finish columns, I have, essentially, a calendar, with each column representing a month (e.g. J for January, F for February, M, A, etc.).  In this calendar, I'd like to fill the two cells that indicate the start and finish date.  For example, if my `Start` value was Jan 2013 and my `Finish` value was March 2013, it would apply the fill to those respective cells.

I have explored the "Conditional Formatting" menu, and I assume I have to use a formula, but I'm not really sure how to implement a formula.  Is this the best method?  Are there any other ways?  Would VB simplify this task?

I assume that I could apply conditional formatting to each cell, something like the following pseudocode:

```
=IF(startDate is January 2013) then use the formatting defined in this dialog box
=IF(startDate is February 2013) then use the formatting defined in this dialog box
```

And so on for each date.  However, I'm wary of the syntax.  Per [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php), it defines the `=IF` syntax as follows:

```
IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

Clearly, the `condition` is matching the dates, whereas the value_if_true and value_if_false don't really make sense to me, because I'm not returning a value, I'm only formatting the cells conditionally.

Thank you!

Update:  Here is a picture of the general layout, that is, there is a row for each task, which corresponds to the calendar.

[image: Spreadsheet]

Here is the formula I'm trying to use for conditional formatting:

```
=MONTH($B6)=COLUMNS($D6:AM6)
```

I think I need to setup my column headers for months differently.  Right now, they are just single letters as text for brevity sake, but I'll enter a date and format the headers properly.  Will update with progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying there's just a single cell for each month? If so then assuming start date in A2, end date in B2 then 12 month cells in D2:O2 then try this:

Select D2:O2 and apply this formula in conditional formatting

`=MONTH($A2)=COLUMNS($D2:D2)`

apply required format > OK

Comment: Thank you.  I should have elaborated.  Each row in my spreadsheet is a task, which has a corresponding Start and End date.  I entered the date as `=DATE(2013, 1, 10)` and applied the conditional formatting to D6:AM6, but it's not working.  See the update to my initial post.

Comment: Do you want to apply to just start date and end date or all cells between the two? It would be simpler if you had dates in row 2 - they can be formatted to look the same as now - put 1/1/2013 in D2 and custom format as MMMMM to show just J and now in E2 use this formula copied across `=EDATE(D2,1)` - format all dates the same as previous - is that a problem?

Comment: No, actually, I didn't realize the dates were just text.  So I re-entered the dates as `=DATE()` instead of just text and formatted them accordingly.  What do you think would be easier, selecting all months within the range or just the beginning and end months?

Comment: If you format row 2 as suggested above then this formula in conditional formatting can format all dates between the two `=(D$2>=$B6-DAY($B6)+1)*(D$2<=$C6-DAY($C6)+1)` apply to just D6 and copy to the rest or apply to the range D6:AM20 or similar depending on the number of rows

Comment: This works very well.  At first, I thought it didn't, but then I realized it takes several seconds for Excel to re-draw the screen.  Thank you very much.

Comment: What formula would I use if I wanted to break down this spreadsheet into smaller intervals?  For example http://i.imgur.com/WdbrfLz.png , where each month is broken down into four weeks?  I've tried setting D8 formatting to `=(D$3>=$B8-DAY($B8)+1)*(D$3<=$C9-DAY($C9)+1)` and copying it across the row but it does not format a single cell.  Thanks!